# Convert an XML file into another according a given XSD

Tags: php, xml, xsd

I have to modify a bunch of XMLs files to make them compliant to a given XSD. I know how to read or write an XML. I already know how to validate a generic XML against a given XSD, however, since the XSD is quite complex I'm looking for a solution to save me the burden to check every single node.

Otherwise, also the mere converter to produce an empty XML to be filled in a second passage would be appreciated.

I've heard about XSL, but it looks like only works with XSL stylesheets.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I have an XML document which says `<everything answer="42" />` and a schema for a document format with nodes called `<foo>` and `<bar>`, I'm going to need more than just the two XSDs to know how to convert the data. That "something else" could be a PHP script, or it could be an XSLT script, or ... anything, really. Perhaps there's some way you can narrow down your question to exactly what part you're hoping to automate, or some examples of the kind of modifications you need to make?

Comment: Suppose I encounter the following xpath: `document\code`, it sould be translated into `document\number`. Ok, I suppose  it's up to me to provide a correct relationshipt of convertion, but it's not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

> I have to modify a bunch of XMLs files to make them compliant to a given XSD. I know how to read or write an XML. I already know how to validate a generic XML against a given XSD,

All quite typical.

> however, since the XSD is quite complex I'm looking for a solution to save me the burden to check every single node.

This part appears to reflect a misunderstanding of validation.

The validating parser itself takes on the burden of checking every single node, leaving you with the substantially smaller task of addressing validation issues that it reports to you via diagnostic messages.

> Otherwise, also the mere converter to produce an empty XML to be filled in a second passage would be appreciated.

There are tools that can instantiate an XSD with a starter XML document that's valid against the XSD.  Such tools can be helpful in creating a new XML document that conforms to an XSD, not in validating existing XML documents.

> I've heard about XSL, but it looks like only works with XSL stylesheets.

XSLT would help if you wanted to transform one XML document to another via an mapping you specify via templates.  Starting with XSLT 2.0, there's support for obtaining type information from XSDs.  However, none of this is designed to help with correcting validation errors in an automated manner.

Comment: I've seen a couple of examples, but they're based on html tags to produce  html pages.

Comment: You've seen a couple of examples  of what?

Comment: Of XSL files. It looks like they are used to match specific XML nodes to produce snippets of HTML code. I suppose I could write a template to translate an XML into another.

Comment: Yes, if you find validations repairs that are numerous and that you feel you could automate categorically, you might write XSLT to map from the invalid XML documents to valid XML documents.

Comment: @Daniele Translating one XML document into another is precisely what XSLT was designed to achieve. It can be used to produce things which aren't valid XML as well, but those are the special cases, not the main purpose of the language.